# Rendered after ActionEvent

Tags: jsf, rendering

I want that `inputText` will be rendered on page after click on the button without entire reload of the page. Consider the facelet 1.xhtml with following  components:

```
<h:commandButton id="show" value="Show" actionListener="#{f.rend}"/>
<h:inputText id="usrname" binding="#{f.usrname}" rendered="false"/>
```

and managed bean

```
@Named("f")
@RequestScoped
private HtmlInputText usrname;
//getter,setter
public void rend(ActionListener e){
//How this method must be implemented?
}
```

Comment: This is the *n*-th time that I had to remove `[java]` tag from your JSF-related question. Don't you pay attention to the edits made by other users? Can you please stop putting the `[java]` tag in everytime? It only pollutes `[java]` tag with questions not about Java and often only attracts "know-it-better" nitwits who posts nonsense comments/answers while they know nothing about JSF. Some users even downvote because they don't understand anything form what you ask.

Comment: @BalusC I'm understand you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send an ajax (partial) request instead of a full request. You can use `<f:ajax>` inside the command component for this. It has a `render` attribute taking a spaceseparated collection of client IDs which needs to be updated. Then, the input component's `rendered` attribute must be a dynamic value expression referring a bean property instead of a hardcoded value of `false`. E.g. a `boolean` property. You just have to set that property to `true` then. You don't and shouldn't need to bind the whole component to the bean. That's poor practice.

All in all, this should do:

```
<h:commandButton id="show" value="Show" action="#{bean.setShow(true)}">
    <f:ajax render="group" />
</h:commandButton>
<h:panelGroup id="group">
    <h:inputText id="username" rendered="#{bean.show}" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

with (assuming JSF 2.2, with `@ViewScoped` for reasons mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope/7031941#7031941))

```
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class Bean {

    private boolean show;

    public boolean isShow() {
        return show;
    }

    public void setShow(boolean show) {
        this.show = show;
    }

}
```